# How can I split cell value over multiple cells based on a maximum value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split

I have a table which look's up raw data for the number of hours in a particular day an event occurred. When the event goes longer than 24 hours, it does not split it across multiple days but instead lumps the entire value in one day.

How do I go about splitting this data across multiple days, with a cap of 24 and the remainder on the last day?

Example:

[image: Example table image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the formula in all but the first row:

```
=MAX(0,MIN(24,A3+SUM(A$2:A2)-SUM(B$2:B2)))
```

It calculates the unhandled remainder for all of the previous rows, and adds it to the hours on the current row (maxing it at 24).

The first row doesn't have 'previous data', so this only needs the following formula:

```
=MIN(24,A2)
```

[image]